# TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first (Segmentation using yolact edge)

Tags: python, pytorch, image-segmentation, tensor

I am running segmentation on yolact edge. I am trying to find coordinates of the minimu and maximum x and y pixel coordinated of the mask using my own algorithm.
I am trying to convert the values of a tuple to numpy. However I am getting the follwoing errror

```
TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.
```

Code

```
    xmin = []
    xmax = []
    y = []
    print(np.shape(t[3]))
    print(type(t[3][:][:][:]))
    #row = (t[3][1][360][:]==1).nonzero(as_tuple=True) 
    for i in range (0, 2):
        t_cpu = t[3].clone().detach().cpu()
        horizontal_translation = torch.where(t[3][i][:][:]==1)
        print(horizontal_translation)
        horizontal_translation_numpy = np.asarray(horizontal_translation[1])
        x_min = np.amin(horizontal_translation_numpy)
        x_max = np.amax(horizontal_translation_numpy)
        np.append(xmin,x_min)
        np.append(xmax, x_max)
    print(xmin)
    print(xmax)
```

Note:
t is a pytorch tensor that is output by the default program that contains mask data in t[3]. How do I fix this?

Output:

```
torch.Size([2, 720, 1280])
<class 'torch.Tensor'>
(tensor([105, 105, 105,  ..., 503, 503, 503]), tensor([427, 428, 429,  ..., 468, 469, 470]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eval.py", line 1303, in <module>
    evaluate(net, dataset)
  File "eval.py", line 928, in evaluate
    evalimage(net, inp, out, detections=detections, image_id="0")
  File "eval.py", line 621, in evalimage
    img_numpy = prep_display(preds, frame, None, None, undo_transform=False)
  File "eval.py", line 198, in prep_display
    horizontal_translation_numpy = np.asarray(horizontal_translation[1])
  File "/home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py", line 83, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
  File "/home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 480, in __array__
    return self.numpy()
TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
xmin = []
xmax = []
y = []
print(np.shape(t[3]))
print(type(t[3][:][:][:]))
#row = (t[3][1][360][:]==1).nonzero(as_tuple=True) 
for i in range (0, 2):
    t_cpu = t[3].clone().detach().cpu()
    horizontal_translation = torch.where(t[3][i][:][:]==1)
    print(horizontal_translation)
    horizontal_translation_numpy = horizontal_translation.cpu().numpy()
    x_min = np.amin(horizontal_translation_numpy)
    x_max = np.amax(horizontal_translation_numpy)
    np.append(xmin,x_min)
    np.append(xmax, x_max)
print(xmin)
print(xmax)
```

Comment: I want the coordinates of the extreme pixels of the mask (both x and y). How can I do this?

Comment: what is your `horizontal_translation_numpy`?

Comment: So, basically, horizontal_translation_numpy and horizontal_translation contains two tensors as returned by torch.where(). The second tensor contains all the x coodrinates of th pixels which are a part of the mask of the apple detected. The first tensor contains all the rows that the pixels are a part of from the mask.

Answer (score 2):

Does

```
horizontal_translation.cpu().numpy()
```

not work?

Comment: Phrase your solution as an answer. If it is a suggestion, then write it as a comment.

Comment: @Xiddoc He can't comment. At least 50 rep is needed.